# Is there a simple way to get the size of a fetched page with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm scraping a bunch of websites using Selenium with the command `driver.get(url)` and I would need to know the size of the fetched web-pages in bytes.

Is there a simple way to do this, and if not, how have you guys done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this

```
logging_prefs = {'performance' : 'INFO'}    
caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
caps['loggingPrefs'] = logging_prefs
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
```

To calculate the total:

```
total_bytes = []
for entry in driver.get_log('performance'):
        if "Network.dataReceived" in str(entry):
            r = re.search(r'encodedDataLength\":(.*?),', str(entry))
            total_bytes.append(int(r.group(1)))
            mb = round((float(sum(total_bytes) / 1000) / 1000), 2)
```

For future reference, it is possible to request this information from the browser by Python. However, at the time of writing no browser supports this feature for this specific data yet.
More information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/encodedBodySize#Return_Value).